# Why does a class constraint prevent me from defining a row type

Tags: purescript

Say I try to define `type Test o e = Nub o e => e`

Then I get an error on the final `e` telling me it can't match `#Type` with `Type`

But `type Test o e = Nub o e => Record e` works fine, so I suppose it doesn't want me to use a row type variable as the result of my definition.

And then `type Test (e :: #Type) = e` does work, so there's nothing wrong with having a `#Type` there normally.

So something about the `Nub` constraint is changing the rules about what sort of type I can define, but I don't see how. What's going on here?

Comment: But this fails as well: `type Test = Eq Int => ()`. It seems that constraints solver is not kind polymorphic and just expects `Type` on the right hand side. Of course I can talk b*** as I'm not a "compiler guy" ;-)